# Unable to get signed in user's profile from google plus in android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

My code works for getting connected and retrieving user email ID :

```
 String account = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

But when I am trying to get user profile, it contains null info.Here is my code.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).build();

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

account = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
                .setResultCallback(this);

        String personName = "Unknown";
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
        }
}
```

Here , Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) shows null.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I have added the scope like  .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

Comment: Have you enabled the google+ APi? Take a look here https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started